# How to introduce blank lines into a pandas dataframe at certain spaces?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Repeat Time     gene_x        indep                 
1      0     5.776279           0
       15    5.874170           0
       30    5.755308           0
       60    5.846254           0
       90    5.631789           0
       120   5.949003           0
       150   5.795068           0
       180   6.133209           0
2      0     5.620326           0
       15    5.639778           0
       30    5.808577           0
       60    5.821405           0
       90    5.805597           0
       120   5.766372           0
       150   6.041138           0
       180   6.109810           0
3      0     5.791153           0
       15    5.856052           0
       30    5.930233           0
       60    5.633090           0
       90    5.940040           0
       120   5.815974           0
       150   6.026407           0
       180   6.052912           0
```

I need to write this data to file, one gene per file with the repeats separated by a blank line. My approach is to introduce black lines into the frame before writing to file so my question is how can I add a blank line after every `180` index?

(note also that both `Repeat` and `Time` are indexes)

The resulting frame should look something like this:

```
Repeat Time     gene_x        indep                 
1      0     5.776279           0
       15    5.874170           0
       30    5.755308           0
       60    5.846254           0
       90    5.631789           0
       120   5.949003           0
       150   5.795068           0
       180   6.133209           0
       NaN   NaN                NaN
2      0     5.620326           0
       15    5.639778           0
       30    5.808577           0
       60    5.821405           0
       90    5.805597           0
       120   5.766372           0
       150   6.041138           0
       180   6.109810           0
       NaN     NaN             NaN
3      0     5.791153           0
       15    5.856052           0
       30    5.930233           0
       60    5.633090           0
       90    5.940040           0
       120   5.815974           0
       150   6.026407           0
       180   6.052912           0
        NaN    NaN              NaN
```

I'd also be open to any alternative approach that anybody can suggest to write data of this format to file with the extra blank lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This works in one line

```
df.append(df.loc[[(1, np.nan), (2, np.nan),(3, np.nan)]]).sort_index()
```

Also this

```
df.append(df.reindex([(1, np.nan), (2, np.nan),(3, np.nan)])).sort_index()
```

Or this

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3], [np.nan]])
df.reindex(df.index.append(mi)).sort_index()
```

You can create a new multiindex and then reindex your original dataframe.

```
time = df.index.get_level_values('Time').unique().tolist() + [np.nan]
repeat = df.index.get_level_values('repeat').unique().tolist()
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([repeat, time], names=['repeat', 'Time'] )
df.reindex(mi)

               gene_x  indep
repeat Time                 
1      0     5.776279    0.0
       15    5.874170    0.0
       30    5.755308    0.0
       60    5.846254    0.0
       90    5.631789    0.0
       120   5.949003    0.0
       150   5.795068    0.0
       180   6.133209    0.0
       NaN        NaN    NaN
2      0     5.620326    0.0
       15    5.639778    0.0
       30    5.808577    0.0
       60    5.821405    0.0
       90    5.805597    0.0
       120   5.766372    0.0
       150   6.041138    0.0
       180   6.109810    0.0
       NaN        NaN    NaN
3      0     5.791153    0.0
       15    5.856052    0.0
       30    5.930233    0.0
       60    5.633090    0.0
       90    5.940040    0.0
       120   5.815974    0.0
       150   6.026407    0.0
       180   6.052912    0.0
       NaN        NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Hi Ted, the problem with this is that I specifically need the repeats to be formatted in the way I described in the question. I appreciate its weird to want to introduce blank lines but its the required format for the next stage of my workflow. Thanks for the suggestion though.